# Geometry Problem (non parallel lines are perpendicular)

Tags: geometry

In the below figure, the measures of the sides trapezoid $ABCD$ are given. If the non-parallel sides of the trapezoid are perpendicular, then $AC^2 + BD^2 = {}$?

1. $DC^2 + AB^2$
2. $BD^2 + DC^2$
3. $DC + AB$
4. $BD + DC$

> [image: Problem statement]

Answer (score 0):

Extend $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ to their intersection $O$. Since we are told that $\overleftrightarrow{AD}$ and $\overleftrightarrow{BC}$ are perpendicular, $\angle AOB$ is right. Thus you have the following applications of the Pythagorean theorem.

- $AC^2 = AO^2 + CO^2$
- $BD^2 = DO^2 + BO^2$
- $AB^2 = AO^2 + BO^2$
- $CD^2 = CO^2 + DO^2$

Can you figure it out from there?

Comment: I think that if we extended AD and BC they won't be perpendicular, i think that the question means that the figure itself won't be the same,it might turns into rectangular,as long as the non-parallel sides are perperndicular.

Comment: @AhmedEssam - you are wrong about that. The meaning of the statement "If $P$, then $Q$" is that the statement $Q$ must hold whenever $P$ holds. When $P$ is false, it tells us nothing about the truth or falsity of $Q$. I.e. When $P$ is false, "If $P$, then $Q$" is true regardless of whether $Q$ is true or false. In this case, you are asked to complete the statement $Q$ to make "If the non-parallel sides are perpendicular, then $Q$" true. For this, you need $Q$ to be true when "the non-parallel sides are perpendicular" is true. And we don't have to worry about when they are not perpendicular.

Comment: Also, the trapezoid is not rectangular when these sides are perpendicular. To be rectangular, $\overline{AD}$ and $\overline{BC}$ have to be parallel (and perpendicular to the other two parallel sides, but not to each other). Instead, this trapezoid is the result of cutting a right triangle by a line parallel to the hypotenuse, making the hypotenuse and cut line the two parallel sides, while the remaining portions of the two legs form the non-parallel sides.